# How can I fire two cameras simultaneously with different settings but the exact same view?

Tags: lens, dslr, optics

I have an idea I want to play around with and I was hoping something already exists for it but google has turned up nothing.

I want to use two cameras synchronized to fire at the exact same time and have the exact same view point.

I was thinking some kind of mirrors or a crazy rig that allows 2 cameras to share a fully manual lens.

Of course one of the 2 cameras will either be configured for different exposure settings or have a physical filter sitting somewhere before the sensor.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try semitransparent mirror:

[image: using semitransparent mirror to capture the same scene with two cameras]

Answer (score 1):

Easy – You use a beam-splitter. Search the web for beam-splitter or semi-silvered mirror. If you use a semi-silvered mirror, it is placed at a 45⁰ angle before the camera lens. You can buy one that transmits 50% and reflects 50%. One camera images thru the mirror, the other is set at a 90⁰ angle. The second camera has the same view (same parallax). 
Semi-silvered mirrors have a long history of use in photography. In the early days of color photography, three black & white films were exposed simultaneously. One filtered red, one green, and one, blue. This is the stuff of early Technicolor and three shot still cameras.

Holography uses the semi-silvered mirrors – see optical supply houses.

Answer (score 0):

Some cameras already do something like that internally - 3 sensor color cameras have a rig like that internally to split light, so it is definitely possible. I do not know of anything that would do that however, outside of a camera in itself.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your hacking skills there are wireless lenses from e.g. [Sony](http://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/interchangeable-lens-cameras/ilce-qx1-body-kit) or [Olympus](http://www.getolympus.com/us/en/air-a01.html). This would probably be the easiest way but you probably would have to write your own software so you're able to connect more than one device to it.

Good news are [the API is Open Source](http://opc.olympus-imaging.com/) for at least the olympus but I don't know how far that would get you.

Comment: How do you suggest the cameras have the *exact* same view?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Two devices would be connected to the same lens, which also includes the sensor. What first sounded like a feasible idea doesn't help much in the end because even if you could connect more than one device to these things it's not possible to get them to control the shutter at the exact same time with different settings, some oversight from my side.

Comment: Could you give an example of where I can buy the device you're proposing to use which connects two cameras to the same lens?

Comment: As I said, there's none such device I know of, but the Olympus one (linked in my answer above) has at least an open API which potentionally could be used to connect two phones. You wouldn't connect a camera to them since these things have their own sensor.

Comment: The Sony device you mention is not a lens per se; it's a complete digicam with no viewfinder or screen. If it were possible to simultaneously interface it to two distinct phones/cameras, all they'd be sharing is a copy of the same captured image file.