# Point two cameras through the same lens, with the same perspective

Tags: optics

I had an idea recently, that would involve two separate cameras, capturing at the same time, with the exact same perspective- Which I mean as, 1:1 the EXACT same perspective, as if both of the cameras were simultaneously in the same spacial position, aimed through the same lens, capturing the exact same image. the 3D camera is not an option, as there is a minute space between the lenses, and i wouldn't want to perform this effect in post, while i probably could. Is there such a way to do what I'm looking for here? I've considered some kind of mirror apparatus, similar to what is used in dealing with teleprompters, but from my experience, this has the potential do degrade quality. Am i wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a beam splitter to record two images using the same lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83518/can-i-use-a-beam-splitter-to-record-two-images-using-the-same-lens)

Comment: Why don't you use one camera, take a picture, and then make a copy of the file, or am I missing the point? What do you need 2 cameras capturing exactly the same image for?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fire two cameras simultaneously with different settings but the exact same view?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71877/how-can-i-fire-two-cameras-simultaneously-with-different-settings-but-the-exact)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [beam splitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter) and direct the 2 resulting beams to the 2 different cameras. The downside is that each will receive half as much light, so you'd need to compensate by one or more of: increasing the light in the scene, opening the aperture wider, or exposing the scene longer.

Comment: The bigger downside is that for normal SLR optics (or c-mount lenses as on security cameras etc. there isn't room behind the lens. The focus would be somewhere near the middle of the beamsplitter. Optics to address this would be more expensive and complex than a second identical lens and using a large beamsplitter in front of the lenses. That however would be hard to align perfectly as you'd have to move a whole camera.

Answer (score 1):

Early methods of shooting color pictures took three sequential pictures, one with red, one with green, and one with blue filter. This method was superseded by a “three shot” camera. Using semitransparent mirrors inside the camera, three images were simultaneously exposed. The original Technicolor movie camera used such a scheme.  You can, using a first surface semitransparent mirror available from Edmund Optics   www.edmundoptics.com.

A semitransparent mirror is set before the camera, at a 45⁰angle. Fifty percent of the light from the vista passes through the mirror to a camera behind, and fifty percent is reflected off to the side to be imaged by a second camera. Procure a half-silvered mirror and build the fixture.

Mount a telescope objective lens with long focal length, perhaps 200 or 300mm before the mirror, cover all with light proof black fabric.

Best of luck!